Make child sticky while parent scrolls
Let's say I have a structure similar to this:
<div id="list" style="width: 500px; height: 300px; overflow: auto;">
  <div id="list_wrapper" style="width: 700px;">
    <div class="row" style="width: 100%; height: 50px;">
      <span style="display: inline-block; width: 200px;">Title</span>
      <span>Content</span>
    </div>
    <!-- more rows -->
  </div>
</div>

The list here can scroll horizontally since the list_wrapper is larger than the list itself. I would like to archive that the Title span of the row stays sticky to the left of the list when it is scrolled horizontally but I'm not sure how to do it. Is this behavior possible with CSS only?

I gave the elements a background-color to distinguish them.
It is possible to give the Title element a position: sticky;left: 0.


<div id="list" style="width: 500px; height: 300px; overflow: auto;background:green;">
  <div id="list_wrapper" style="width: 700px;background:red;">
    <div class="row" style="width: 100%; height: 50px;">
      <span style="display: inline-block; width: 200px;position: sticky;left: 0;background: blue;">Title</span>
      <span>Content</span>
    </div>
    <!-- more rows -->
  </div>
</div>




Thanks you :) But this only work if the list is top left of the page, doesn't it? What if my list is somewhere else on the page?

Do you mean like this https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/y8neshLu/4/ ?

Sorry you were absolutely right! From testing I still had an overflow: hidden in between, after I removed it, it works perfectly, thanks :)
